# Unable to make nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am trying to make a simple quiz program using python in Pycharm and I am unable to make a nested list in this program.

```
question = ["1. Grand Central Terminal, Park Avenue, New York is the world's", "2. Entomology is the science that studies",  "3. Eritrea, which became the 182nd member of the UN in 1993, is in the continent of"]
options = [
["A. Largest railway station             B. Highest railway station"
 "C. Longest railway station             D. None of the above"]
["A. Behavior of human beings                                     B. Insects"
 "C. The origin and history of technical and scientific terms     D. The formation of rocks"]
["A. Asia         B. Africa"
 "C. Europe       D. Australia"]
]
```

This nested list is giving me the following error:
`Unexpected type(s): (str) Possible type(s): (SupportsIndex) (slice)` 
It would be a great help if anyone can guide me how to solve this error.

Comment: Maybe `options` is missing commas?

Comment: @TheCodingPenguin Yes, I tried that but it's not working.

Comment: @9769953 Yes got it, thanks. It was a silly mistake of commas. I was putting it at a wrong place.

Comment: @9769953 I appreciate your advice but I am solving questions and it is told to use lists only.

Comment: @IRONMAN Please accept an answer that it solves tour problem so that this question is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot some comma's.
Your options list should look something like this:

```
options = [
    ["A. Largest railway station", "B. Highest railway station", "C. Longest railway station", "D. None of the above"],
    ["A. Behavior of human beings", "B. Insects", "C. The origin and history of technical and scientific terms", "D. The formation of rocks"],
    ["A. Asia", "B. Africa", "C. Europe", "D. Australia"]
]
```

Preferably You would have your questions and answers in a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

That would look something like this:

```
quiz = {
    "1. Grand Central Terminal, Park Avenue, New York is the world's": 
        ["A. Largest railway station", "B. Highest railway station", "C. Longest railway station", "D. None of the above"],
    "2. Entomology is the science that studies":
        ["A. Behavior of human beings", "B. Insects", "C. The origin and history of technical and scientific terms", "D. The formation of rocks"],
    "3. Eritrea, which became the 182nd member of the UN in 1993, is in the continent of": 
        ["A. Asia", "B. Africa", "C. Europe", "D. Australia"]
}
```

You could also look into automatically setting the indexes of your questions and answers, which would make your code easier to modify later.